# Jon Rogawski Calculus Textbook Section 4.3 Exercise 53

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, solution-verification

Here is the question from the cited textbook.

Suppose we have two functions $f$ and $g$ such that $f(0)=g(0)$ and $f'(x) \leq g(x)$ for all $x \geq 0$. Prove that $f(x) \leq g(x)$ for all $x \geq 0$.

Here's my answer.

Proof:

If $f(0)=g(0)$ and $f'(x) \leq g'(x)$ for $x \geq 0$, then that means $ f'(x)-g'(x)=(f(x)-g(x))' \leq 0$ for $x \geq 0$. Because $(f(x)-g(x))' \leq 0$ for $x \geq 0$, $f(x)-g(x)$ is decreasing for $x \geq 0$. Since $f(0)=g(0)=k$ where $k$ can be any real constant,$f(0)-g(0)=k-k=0$. Using the fact that $(f(x)-g(x))' \leq 0$ for $x \geq 0$ and that $f(x)-g(x)$ is decreasing for $x \geq 0$, we can say that for all $x \gt 0$, $f(x)-g(x) \leq 0$ or $f(x) \leq g(x)$.

**QED**

Is this good? Thanks.

By the way, people have talked about citing the textbook in the title. Is my citation sufficient?

Comment: Looks good! Was the fact that a function with a nonpositive derivative is decreasing proven in this section of the textbook?  Then I would cite that theorem by number.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I don't think that theorem was directly proven, other than the statement being a consequence of how a function that is monotonic on a certain interval behaves. If the derivative is less than zero for all numbers in the interval, then the function is decreasing on that interval

Comment: OK, proofs in a math class need to reference previously established theorems.  So nail down the source of that result.  Or you can appeal directly to the MVT.

Comment: Thanks. Actually I won't formally learn how to write rigorous proofs good until the fall, so this is helping me get a head start.

Comment: You're doing great

Comment: Haha... Thanks.

Comment: In question at second line there is $f'(x) \leq g(x)$, while should be $f'(x) \leq g'(x)$.

Comment: You are correct that "Because $(f(x)-g(x))'\leq 0$, $f(x)-g(x)$ is decreasing", but you need to reference the result you are using. At that point you could actually stop since you've got to the answer. The rest of your answer is so much verbiage.

Comment: Okay, but what result implies that? It seems like that just comes from the definition of a derivative. Since the slope of the tangent is less than zero for $x \geq 0$, f(x)-g(x) is decreasing for $x \geq 0$.

Comment: In the second paragraph please write $f'(x)\le g'(x)$